# Scrape links from webpage with XML declaration

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page: https://inbio-discover.com/#downloads

The body of the page scraped using Selenium is copied/pasted below. EDIT: Also tried with BeautifulSoup (unable to get table data)

```
<body data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen-32509057_16="296" data-gtm-vis-polling-id-32509057_16="19" data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-32509057_16="296" data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time-32509057_16="1500">
<div class="browser-warning-banner" id="browser-warning-banner">
<div class="browser-warning-banner__content">
<h3>Warning your browser does not appear to be supported</h3>
<div class="seo-content-text">Try changing to one of the following browsers</div>
<div class="browser-warning-banner__content-browsers">
<a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/" target="_blank">Google Chrome</a> / <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox" target="_blank">Mozilla Firefox</a>
</div>
<button class="browser-warning-banner__ignore-btn" onclick="onIgnoreClick()" type="button">Ignore and proceed</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="view-viewport_page pf-absolute-full"><!-- --> <div class="pf-absolute-full"><!-- --> <!-- --> <!-- --> <!-- --> <!-- --> <!-- --> <!-- --> <nav class="view-navbar navbar-fluid navbar-default" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="navbar-header" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a class="navbar-brand" data-lid="viewPortAppName" data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="#login"><div data-v-95dc1fe6=""><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->
<svg height="42" id="svg96" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 838.51 152.31" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<metadata id="metadata102">
<rdf:rdf>
<cc:work rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"></dc:type>
<dc:title></dc:title>
</cc:work>
</rdf:rdf>
</metadata>
<defs id="defs100">
<style>.a{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>inbio_Discover_white</title><path class="a" d="M341.46,1.75c18.16,0,29.76,10.72,29.76,28.45v91.91c0,17.73-12,28.45-29.76,28.45H310.6V1.75Zm-5.91,21.89v105h5.25a5.34,5.34,0,0,0,5.47-5.69V29.33a5.34,5.34,0,0,0-5.47-5.69Z"></path><path class="a" d="M394.42,28.45a14.34,14.34,0,0,1-14.23-14.22,14.23,14.23,0,1,1,28.45,0A14.33,14.33,0,0,1,394.42,28.45Zm-12,122.11V42h23.85V150.56Z"></path><path class="a" d="M461.82,93.23c9.19,5.25,10.94,12.25,10.94,19.91v9.41c0,20.35-11.6,29.76-29.11,29.76-18.38,0-28.88-9-28.88-30V112.7h24.07v13.79c0,3.28,2.19,5.69,5,5.69,2.63,0,4.82-2.41,4.82-5.69v-11.6c0-2.41-1.32-5-4.6-7L426.36,98c-7.22-3.94-11.59-10.94-11.59-22.54V70.69c0-17.95,7.87-30.42,29.1-30.42,21.67,0,28.89,10.28,28.89,30.85v7.23H448.69v-12c0-3.5-2.19-5.91-5-5.91s-4.81,2.41-4.81,5.91v9.85a7.57,7.57,0,0,0,3.94,6.34Z"></path><path class="a" d="M538.41,111.17v14.45c0,17.07-12.91,26.69-28.67,26.69-16,0-28.67-9.62-28.67-26.69V67c0-17.07,12.69-26.7,28.67-26.7,15.76,0,28.67,9.63,28.67,26.7V80.32H514.55v-14c0-3.5-2.19-5.69-4.81-5.69-2.85,0-4.82,2.19-4.82,5.69v60.18c0,3.28,2,5.47,4.82,5.47,2.62,0,4.81-2.19,4.81-5.47V111.17Z"></path><path class="a" d="M546.28,67c0-17.07,12.7-26.7,28.67-26.7,15.76,0,28.67,9.63,28.67,26.7v58.65c0,17.07-12.91,26.69-28.67,26.69-16,0-28.67-9.62-28.67-26.69Zm33.49-.66c0-3.5-2.19-5.69-4.82-5.69-2.84,0-4.81,2.19-4.81,5.69v60.18c0,3.28,2,5.47,4.81,5.47,2.63,0,4.82-2.19,4.82-5.47Z"></path><path class="a" d="M625.5,150.56,608.65,42h24.51l6.13,74.4h.44l7-74.4h23.42L652.86,150.56Z"></path><path class="a" d="M731.42,102H697.94v24.51c0,3.28,2,5.47,4.81,5.47,2.63,0,4.82-2.19,4.82-5.47V115.33h23.85v10.29c0,17.07-12.91,26.69-28.67,26.69-16,0-28.67-9.62-28.67-26.69V67c0-17.07,12.92-26.7,28.89-26.7,15.76,0,28.45,9.63,28.45,26.7ZM697.94,86.44h9.63V66.31c0-3.5-2.19-5.69-4.82-5.69-2.84,0-4.81,2.19-4.81,5.69Z"></path><path class="a" d="M764.9,50.77c2.41-5.91,7-10.5,14.44-10.5A14.88,14.88,0,0,1,786.78,42l-6.34,24.29a13.52,13.52,0,0,0-7.23-2c-5.47,0-8.09,3.5-8.09,9.19v77H741.26V42h23.2v8.75Z"></path><path class="a" d="M795.15,40.18V10.79h-6.43V3.88h20.4v6.91h-6.75V40.18Zm36.29,0V16.57l-5.62,13.49L820.2,16.57V40.18h-7.07V3.88H820l6.1,14.62,5.78-14.62h6.59v36.3Z"></path><path class="a" d="M14.22,28.45A14.34,14.34,0,0,1,0,14.22,14.49,14.49,0,0,1,14.22,0,14.49,14.49,0,0,1,28.45,14.22,14.35,14.35,0,0,1,14.22,28.45Zm-12,122.11V42H26V150.56Z"></path><path class="a" d="M59.74,48.36c2.63-4.59,7.22-8.09,14.66-8.09,11.38,0,18.6,7.66,18.6,26v84.25H69.15V65.87c0-3.28-1.53-5.25-4.38-5.25-3.06,0-4.81,2-4.81,5.47v84.47H36.11V42H59.3v6.34Z"></path><path class="a" d="M103.16,150.56V1.75h30c20.57,0,30.64,10.94,30.64,29.11V54.71c0,9.85-5.26,16.85-10.73,19.26v1.09c6.79,4.38,10.73,10.29,10.73,20.14v25.38c0,17.73-10.29,30-31.52,30Zm25-85.35h5.47c3.06,0,5.25-2.62,5.25-6.78V30c0-4.59-2.41-7.22-5.91-7.22h-4.81Zm0,20.58v43.55h4.81c3.5,0,5.91-2.41,5.91-6.79V97c0-6.79-.66-11.16-5.91-11.16Z"></path><path class="a" d="M185.53,28.45a14.34,14.34,0,0,1-14.22-14.23,14.23,14.23,0,0,1,28.45,0A14.35,14.35,0,0,1,185.53,28.45Zm-12,122.11V42h23.85V150.56Z"></path><path class="a" d="M207.41,67c0-17.07,12.7-26.7,28.67-26.7,15.76,0,28.67,9.63,28.67,26.7v58.65c0,17.06-12.91,26.69-28.67,26.69-16,0-28.67-9.63-28.67-26.69Zm33.49-.66c0-3.5-2.19-5.69-4.82-5.69-2.84,0-4.81,2.19-4.81,5.69v60.18c0,3.28,2,5.47,4.81,5.47,2.63,0,4.82-2.19,4.82-5.47Z"></path></svg>
</div></a></div> <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="view-navbar_items" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-lid="pagesNavBar" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><li class="" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="#about" style="font-size: 14px;" target="_blank">
                                About
                            </a></li><li class="active" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="" style="font-size: 14px;" target="_self">
                                Search
                            </a></li><li class="" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="#help" style="font-size: 14px;" target="_blank">
                                Help
                            </a></li><!-- --> <li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" style="font-size: 14px;"><div class="faded-menu-text" data-v-95dc1fe6="">TERMS OF USE</div></a></li></ul></div> <!-- --> <div class="navbar-right" data-lid="navbarContainer" data-v-95dc1fe6="" style="margin-top: 10px;"><ul class="view-navbar nav navbar-nav" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><li data-lid="debugItem" data-v-95dc1fe6="" style="display: none; color: grey; font-size: xx-small;"></li> <li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><button aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn dropdown-toggle pf-navbar-menu-button pf-navbar-communicating-button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6="" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer" data-v-95dc1fe6="" style="color: rgb(198, 220, 12);"></span>
                                    Communicating
                                </button></div></li> <!-- --> <!-- --> <li data-lid="settingsMenu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><button aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn dropdown-toggle pf-navbar-menu-button" data-cy="settings.open" data-toggle="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6="" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-v-95dc1fe6=""></span>
                                      Settings
                                    </button> <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" class="dropdown-menu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-cy="customAnnotationsMenu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""></span>
                                        Custom annotations
                                      </a></li></ul></div></li> <li data-lid="appsMenu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><button aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn dropdown-toggle pf-navbar-menu-button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6="" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" data-v-95dc1fe6=""></span>
                                    Apps
                                    </button> <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" class="dropdown-menu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="index.html" target="_blank"><img data-v-95dc1fe6="" src="5447133a649d837a8919f62b252f32de.ico" style="padding-bottom: 2px;"/> inBio Discover™</a></li> <li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="know.html" target="_blank"><img data-v-95dc1fe6="" src="aa9ef2c0c8390ac9ee4ce201ea1c3900.ico" style="padding-bottom: 2px;"/> inBio Know™</a></li> <li class="divider" data-v-95dc1fe6="" role="separator"></li> <li data-v-95dc1fe6=""><a data-v-95dc1fe6="" href="https://www.intomics.com" target="_blank">Intomics Web Page <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" data-v-95dc1fe6=""></span></a></li></ul></div></li> <!-- --> <li data-lid="loginMenu" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><div class="dropdown" data-lid="accountDropdown" data-v-95dc1fe6=""><button aria-expanded="true" class="pf-btn pf-btn-1 dropdown-toggle" data-cy="navigation.signInBtn" data-v-95dc1fe6="" style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-v-95dc1fe6=""></span> <span data-lid="userName" data-v-95dc1fe6=""> Sign In </span></button> <!-- --> <!-- --></div></li></ul></div></div></div> <!-- --></nav> <div class="view-viewport_scrollable" data-cy="viewport.scrollable.content" data-lid="scrollable" style="top: 50px;"><div class="banner-container" data-cy="messageBanner.container" data-v-923f33b4=""></div> <div></div></div></div></div>
<script src="./browser_detect.js?cache=20210209151900___2c4a2451__1.3.0RC1"></script>
<script>
            var domBannerWarning = document.getElementById("browser-warning-banner")
            function onIgnoreClick() {
                document.body.removeChild(domBannerWarning)
            }

            if (window.InBio.browserDetection.browser === 'ie' || window.InBio.browserDetection.browser === 'opera') {
                domBannerWarning.setAttribute("style", "display: block;")
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!window.InBio.appLoaded) {
                    domBannerWarning.setAttribute("style", "display: block;")
                }
            }, 30000);

            window.InBio = window.InBio || {}
            window.InBio.VERSION = '20210209151900___2c4a2451__1.3.0RC1'
            window.InBio.mapApiUrl = 'map/api'
        </script>
<script src="./app_map.js?cache=20210209151900___2c4a2451__1.3.0RC1"></script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe height="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K9P4WLQ" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
</body></html>
```

I'm having trouble getting the table data, which I can see when I visit the page in my browser, to show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try the same with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Thanks, updated my post. I'm unable to get table data with bs4 as well.